# Salesforce package error error “You can't specify version for namespace sf_com_apps because this namespace is not installed to your organization.”

Tags: managed-package

I'm having an odd issue where a package I've been maintaining for a while has now decided it is dependent on Salesforce Connected Apps (namespace sf_com_apps). Even when I try to remove the dependency by editing the metadata of the pages, components and lightning components it's being automatically added back. I don't believe any of my code is actually using anything from this package and I don't want my users to have to install it (as there isn't an easy way to do it, you seem to have to log into the org through workbench for it to install).

The only thing I can think that might have had something to do with this is upgrading API versions for all my code to 45.

The error the org will receive if installing my package but sf_com_apps doesn't exist is: "You can't specify version for namespace sf_com_apps because this namespace is not installed to your organization."

Comment: I've had this in sandboxes and have always managed to remove the dependancy, never with the actual package though.

Comment: So packages always have this dependency now? Like all packages created now will have this error if sf_com_apps isn't installed?

Comment: I wasn't sure where it was coming from tbh, but workbench makes sense. It's not always a dependency.

Answer (score 3):

You can't directly "undo" a dependency once you upload a "released" version that causes the dependency. What you need to do is open a case with Partner Support and request that they roll back all versions that caused the dependency to "beta," at which point you should be able to fix the problem. This will involve uninstalling all affected versions from any orgs they are installed in. It would be ideal to uninstall/delete any apps that should not be in your org, as that can cause packaging issues (as you've unfortunately discovered).

Comment: Awesome, thank you for the info. What I suspect happened is when I copied all my code from my dev into the packaging org the SF connected apps dependency got somehow included. This is going to sound really dumb, but since this is a developer org I'm not able to open a case from that account. How would I go about logging a case with them for this org?

Comment: @Kenji776 If you're an ISV, you'd just log a case through your ISV account. If not, there's probably nothing you can do about it short of building a new package. Managed packages are not to be trifled with, they are very finicky.

Comment: I'd log something through the partner portal and provide the org ID. Good luck though.

Comment: Alright, thanks guys. I'll see about getting a case opened. This package is being developed for a client and they already have a released version that went through security review and all that so building a new package is all but off the table. Lets hope support can help fix this mess or else I'm hosed.

Answer (score 3):

I was actually able to find a fix for this. I uninstalled the Salesforce Connected Apps package which removed the reference to it in all my code. I was then able to upload a new version of the package which did not have the dependency and hence no error! Thanks @sfdcfox for pointing me the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue today when trying to deploy my own package and found this resolution:

TLDR: Search for the namespace (in this case sf_com_apps) in your source and delete + recreate the offending files on your SF dev instance.

In visual studio code search for sf_com_apps and open the offending file: in my case, a meta-xml file.

I deleted this section:

```
<packageVersions>
    <majorNumber>1</majorNumber>
    <minorNumber>7</minorNumber>
    <namespace>sf_com_apps</namespace>
</packageVersions>
```

And then deployed the file to my source org via sfdc.

This didn't work for me, so I had to delete the component in Developer Console and then Re-create it and paste in all the code and save it. Then I added the new aura bundle to my package and recompiled/uploaded it.

That finally worked...

I hope this helps someone.